# How to get a list of similar elements using Ranorex?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, ranorex

A newbie Ranorex, I come from a Selenium Python background.

I can not figure out how to find an array of similar elements in Ranorex. With Selenium, we can use something like:

```
array = webdriver.FindElementsByXpath(xpath)
```

How to do it using Ranorex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranorex has its own set of methods, for examples:

If you are looking for an array of `<div>` elements, you need to:

```
WebDocument webDocument = "/dom[@caption = title of the webpage under test]";
IList <DivTag> array = webDocument.Find<DivTag>(xpath);
```

They are comparable to:

```
driver = Selenium.Chrome();
array = driver.FindElementsByXpath();
```

If you are looking for a group of  element, replace `<DivTag>` with `<ATag>`.

Comment: Furthermore, you can organize xpaths to GUI elements in a repository, and reference those in your code.